# Why is this block not working on my ERB template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

```
<%= render layout: "shared/some_template", 
      locals: {
               variable_value: true 
              } do %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag "ids[]", "ng-value": "sth.id" %>
<% end %>
```

The template on some template has some html and a yield call where the "hidden" field should go but it's not rendering it, it does render everything else inside the template, it just drops the hidden_field_tag part.

Any idea how can I solve this? it works on the HAML version when I tried it, but not on ERB, is that not available for ERB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `&block` to `render`, which is doing nothing with it.

To pass a callback to a partial, build a `lambda` and put it in a local variable:

```
<%= 
  lamb = lambda{ hidden_field_tag 'ids[]', 'ng-value' => 'sth.id' }
  locals = { variable_value: true, callback: lamb }
  render layout: 'shared/some_template', locals: locals
 %>
```

Now inside the template call `<%= callback.call %>`.

(Note, BTW, that I used `'` instead of `"`, because we are not using the special features of `"`. And note I introduced a local variable, `locals`, instead of creatively indenting the `render` call.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it strike you as strange to have all of that in a template?

Comment: I have passed a callback to a partial template before. Views should be dumb - fat, but dumb.

Comment: Just because, why does it work with HAML and not with ERB is it a feature on HAML only?